# How you can unite-merge parts of a sliced string?

Tags: python, pgp

Is there a way to join-merge a sliced string in python so you can get the original string after the slicing? If not with what language this can be achieved? 

I did edit i hope it will help. 

 

I have a text example bellow

begining of pre-sliced text:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

End of pre-sliced text


I slice the text with s[start:stop:step] and in this example i sliced it in 2 parts

```
s = """abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"""
#part 1 result
print (s[0::2])
#part 2 result
print (s[1::2])
```

How can I join the results part1 and part2 so I will get the original pre-sliced text. 

Original pre-sliced text.

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Thank you all for your effort.

Based on Stephan's fourth reply.

```
>>> s, t = """acegikmoqsuwy
... bdfhjlnprtvxz""", """bdfhjlnprtvxzacegikmoqsuwy"""
>>> tmp = list(s + t)
>>> tmp[0::2], tmp[1::2] = s, t
>>> print(''.join(tmp))
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

using it to slice a PGP message in 3

```
s = """hQEMA1H5MO53CAz0AQf+PoxwzD+9TYqGg61W/ng8Umi+mFPneIC4+JlMu2H4mCsx
AzO5APdXJJHRFjSpS01ZeKQQ05xEeHCnjgmWEFCWUVXW77kd/YI9Q01QIyoo8J6y
b9Wu4uFPQiCy2+Fr4SIKtrpOrsbrqG54BPFY66NeQ9NbG217QCbcaUlXHpmokiIc
6T94uTkLRo+Lv2QWzMBfyfyWbuU2lwD+7dD45oRB7cXInM9jQDHL8FKcFutTxPXh
8w/8eCZtPOQwCAX+vnRFT4DtgDotRdagDEswtuPTd8YbpemIa/C01ylExgIVvtLP
JwimeWx9d+nJgL2nx2emaYzN0vNQStOQceWtYxbbJdJJAXniDi7+HApeHyN2JcKu
LFjdTQFaQB0JGdloIXSJBqhOCMXBfd7mJ5c9sY6abE4bfP9/znbqT35y3GVU9RyX
NVKOujgxzi0/xQ==
=DvXG"""
print (s[0::3])
print (s[1::3])
print (s[2::3])
```

and joining it

```
>>> s, t, d = """hMHOC0foz9q6/8iFe4l2mxzAXHjSZQ5enmFUWkYQQoJ
WuQyFStObGBYN9G7bUHoI64kovWBfb2Dd5BXMQLKuxhwetQAvFDDRgsudbm/1EIt
iWdJ22aNNtctbdAi7AH2KLdFBGoSqCB75sa4Pzq5G9XVux0Q
v""", """QA55AA+xDTG1nU+PI+MHC
OPJRS0eQxHjWCV7dI0Io6buFi2rIrrr5P6eN2QclpkcTuL+2zfyul+Do7I9D8ctP
/CPwXnTtodDwP8pICyxVLJmx+gneY0QOeYbJXD+pyJuFTa0dIJhMfmcYbb9nTyVR
Kjz/==X""", """E1M3zQPw+YgWgmmnCJu4sA5dJFp1K0ECgEWX7/91y8y94PC+4Kpsq4F6Qb1CaXmi
9TRLQMyWUw74RcnjHFFTX88ZOC+R4gtaEtTYea0lgvPwe9nLxmzvSQWxJJniHeNc
jQQJlXBOXdJ96Ef/b33UyNOgix=DG"""
tmp = list(s + t + d)
tmp[0::3], tmp[1::3], tmp[2::3] = s, t, d
print(''.join(tmp))
```

you get the Original PGP message

hQEMA1H5MO53CAz0AQf+PoxwzD+9TYqGg61W/ng8Umi+mFPneIC4+JlMu2H4mCsx

AzO5APdXJJHRFjSpS01ZeKQQ05xEeHCnjgmWEFCWUVXW77kd/YI9Q01QIyoo8J6y

b9Wu4uFPQiCy2+Fr4SIKtrpOrsbrqG54BPFY66NeQ9NbG217QCbcaUlXHpmokiIc

6T94uTkLRo+Lv2QWzMBfyfyWbuU2lwD+7dD45oRB7cXInM9jQDHL8FKcFutTxPXh

8w/8eCZtPOQwCAX+vnRFT4DtgDotRdagDEswtuPTd8YbpemIa/C01ylExgIVvtLP

JwimeWx9d+nJgL2nx2emaYzN0vNQStOQceWtYxbbJdJJAXniDi7+HApeHyN2JcKu

LFjdTQFaQB0JGdloIXSJBqhOCMXBfd7mJ5c9sY6abE4bfP9/znbqT35y3GVU9RyX

NVKOujgxzi0/xQ==

=DvXG

Comment: Could you explain it better?

Comment: I don't understand that mix of code and output. Make that actually work, please.

Comment: I agree that this question makes very little sense but String.join is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: If you are going to use the original string _later_, just save it and use it later.  But, if you know how it was deconstructed you can always write something to reconstruct it.

Comment: The resulting original string it will be generated from the slices from someone else not by me. The original string is sliced by A. A sends the slices to B with different methods. B gets the slices (joins-merge) them and has the original string. If the original string is an encrypted PGP message for example an intercepted slice will never be decrypted.

Comment: I added three solutions to my answer that don't miss the "z", and I switched to printing the results since you seemed to think that *"has the \n as changing line"* is an error (it's not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two parts have equal length:

```
>>> s, t = 'acegikmoqsuwy', 'bdfhjlnprtvxz'
>>> print(''.join(a + b for a, b in zip(s, t)))
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

If they're don't:

```
>>> s, t = 'acegikmoqsuwy\nbdfhjlnprtvxz', 'bdfhjlnprtvxzacegikmoqsuwy'
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> print(''.join(a + b for a, b in zip_longest(s, t, fillvalue='')))
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Or:

```
>>> s, t = 'acegikmoqsuwy\nbdfhjlnprtvxz', 'bdfhjlnprtvxzacegikmoqsuwy'
>>> tmp = list(s + t)
>>> tmp[0::2], tmp[1::2] = s, t
>>> print(''.join(tmp))
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Or:

```
>>> s, t = 'acegikmoqsuwy\nbdfhjlnprtvxz', 'bdfhjlnprtvxzacegikmoqsuwy'
>>> print(''.join((s, t)[i % 2][i // 2] for i in range(len(s + t))))
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: or `''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(s, t))`

Comment: You got it Stefan actually the third reply is easy to modify.